# Executing php in an .thtml file in Hero Framework themes

Tags: php, html, frameworks, themes

Is there a way to execute php in thtml files in Hero Framework?

by just placing a

```
<?php echo 'hello world';?>
```

doesn't work in an thtml file.

is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: this question may be a bit to specialized...it seems like the hero framework uses its own templating language. maybe asking in specialized forums for hero framework or CodeIgniter will be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was curious and did a bit of googling:

apparently the Hero Framework uses **smarty** as template engine, which is ...interesting...(Excurse: smarty seems quite sophisticated these days and I know it did a good job of cache handling even a few years ago. On the other hand, it's another layer in your Application, it's another dialect to learn, it's code that has to be interpreted by PHP)

smarty strongly discourages the direct use of pure php in the templates, you can read more here:

[smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/best_practices)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a bit of `.htaccess` to make sure html files parse as PHP.

e.g.:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

However, this command depends on the server setup, more can be found about that [here](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/how-to-parse-html-files-as-php/).

Comment: I don't think this is the problem here. the _t_html files will be loaded/parsed by the framework, not called directly

Comment: Ah right...in that case, surely the framework has some sort of templating system that should be used instead?